# Delphi DataSnap TDSServiceException

Tags: api, rest, http, delphi, datasnap

I'm using Delphi on RAD Studio 10 Seattle to work with a REST API with DataSnap. It's working on most of the HTTP verbs, except with DELETE. There's the function for it, according to the DataSnap documentation, but when I do a request with the DELETE HTTP Verb, it gives-me the exception "Project RESTApi.exe raised exception class TDSServiceException with message 'Command closed or unassigned".

Follow the code of the DELETE function for the DataSnap API.

```
function TSM.CancelLista(const ID_LISTA: integer): TJSONObject;
const
 _DELETE = 'DELETE FROM listas WHERE id = :id';
begin
 with FormPrincipal do
 begin
  DB_Query.Active := false;
  DB_Query.SQL.Text := _DELETE;
  DB_Query.ParamByName('id').Value :=  ID_LISTA;

  Try
    DB_Query.ExecSQL;
    Result.AddPair('Response', 'Lista atualizada com sucesso');
  Except on E : Exception do
    Result.AddPair('Response', E.Message);
  End;
 end;
end;
```

I'm making the requests with a PHP Code Igniter 4.0.4 web app, but already tried it with the Delphi REST Debugger, with the same result.

Comment: Are you certain the exception occurs on the line `DB_Query.ExecSQL`?  If you put a breakpoint on that line and press F7, where *exactly* does the exception occur?  What datatype is DB_Query?

Comment: No, I think it occurs even before it enters the function. I put the breakpoint on the very beginning of the function and it doesn't even is reached. Seems like when the request with the DELETE verb is made and received by the DataSnap API it already triggers the exception

Comment: DB_Query is a FireDAC TFDQuery.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that.  IME, the best way to debug this would be to add a client module to the server (including a form to operate it) and then debug it from there.

Comment: I've tried something like calling the function on another unit, and it seems to be working properly. The issue starts when a HTTP DELETE request is addressed to the API.

Comment: Then possibly a lifetime-management issue related to the FDQuery.

Comment: I changed the entire code of the function to just   
`Result := TJSONObject.Create;
Result.AddPair('Debug', 'Testing DELETE HTTP');`

And the exception persists. I think it's something related to the way DataSnap handle the requests and relate it to the name of the functions (Accept, Cancel, Update...). Maybe changing it from function to procedure?

Comment: Well, what I'd try is to choose another server-side function which utilizes the FDQuery (and works ok), then put breakpoints on TFDQuery.Create and TFDQuery.Destroy and observe when and where they are called from this other function and compare it with the DELETE function.

Comment: But it shouldn't have much with it because it don't work even if the function is empty, that means, not using any TFDQuery at all, or queries from other functions can be interfering?

Comment: Well, you should find that there are several examples of datasnap client/server pairs that come with Delphi, so I think you are going to have to study one of those and see where yours diverges from it.  If you want more help here, I think you'll have to add a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your q.

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't in the API at all, but the requested method wasn't made properly, the method was being sent as ``DELETE`, so the DataSnap API wasn't recognizing it as a command. As the request as being made by Code Igniter 4.0.4 CURLRequest class as following:

```
$reqConfig = [            
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ]            
    ]; 
$verb = '`DELETE`'
$curl->request($verb, 'Listas/'.id_lista, $reqConfig);
```

It was solved changing the `$verb` taking the "`" out.

The API DELETE function is now:

```
function TSM.CancelLista(const ID_LISTA: integer): TJSONObject;
const
  _DELETE = 'DELETE FROM listas WHERE id = :id';
begin
  Result := TJSONObject.Create;
  with FormPrincipal do
  begin
    DB_Query.Active := false;
    DB_Query.SQL.Text := _DELETE;
    DB_Query.ParamByName('id').Value :=  ID_LISTA;

    Try
      DB_Query.ExecSQL;
      Result.AddPair('Response', 'Lista deletada com sucesso');
    Except on E : Exception do
      Result.AddPair('Response', E.Message);
    End;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think you should add your actual code to this answer.  Just saying you've solved the problem without showing how doen't really help future readers, which is what Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: Sure! Edited now